# Can this be done with less code using lambda?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a `List<Person>` (people)  every person has a `List<Kid>` (kids)

If I want to find all the People with kids less than 5 years of age, I would do something like this

```
var peopleWithLittleKids=new List<Person>()

foreach(var p in people)
{
    foreach(var kid in p.Kids)
    {
        if(kid.age<5)
        {
            peopleWithLittleKids.Add(p);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a one line way of doing this using lambda?

Comment: Guys, I didnt give negative votes to any of you, someone is down voting all the answers.

Comment: *"Every person has a `List<Kid>` (kids)"* contradicts the example code you have given, where `p.Kid` is a single object.  Please clarify, as this ambiguity is what is generating the swarm of downvotes on answers.

Comment: Note that your loop approach can be improved since it doesn't `break`s the inner `foreach` when a kid was found (similar to spender's `Any`).

Comment: BTW - Do you want to have `peopleWithLittleKids` contain duplicates of the person?  (The loop above will cause a `Person` to be added *once per young kid*, not once if any kid is <5)...

Comment: @Reed, I could do a select distinct later.

Comment: @developer747: No, as already mentioned, you just need a `break`.

Comment: added a break statement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming people are allowed have more than one child... [insert political statement here...]

```
people.Where(p => p.Kids.Any(k => k.age < 5))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) and [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) extension methods:

```
var peopleWithLittleKids = people.Where(p => p.Kids.Any(k => k.age < 5)).ToList();
```

Note that you can also leave off `ToList()` if you are merely going to iterate through the results (via `foreach`), as that does not require a `List<T>` for the results.

Also - your loop approach will add a `Person` to the list multiple times if they have multiple matching children.  If you want to duplicate this functionality, you could via:

```
var peopleWithLittleKidsContainingDuplicates = people
               .SelectMany(p => p.Kids.Where(k => k.Age < 5).Select(k => p));
```

(This is likely not what you want, and a bug in the original, but this does match the original code...)

Comment: +1 for trying to create the linq counterpart of the original code in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Lambdas alone won't solve your problem. LINQ is the technology that will help you do what you want:

```
var peopleWithLittleKids = people.Where(p => p.Kids.Any(k => k.age < 5).ToList();
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? According to the OP, p.Kid is a single instance rather than a collection.

Comment: According to the OP it's ambiguous. (*"Every person has a `List<Kid>` (kids)"* contradicts the example code.)  I'm not the one who downvoted, but this is probably their rationale for doing so.

Comment: @cdhowie - Guess I should've read the text as well as the code. Fixed.

Comment: But now, there is already a correct answer. Why to repeat it? Upvote it and remove yours.

Comment: @I4V I would say that's a good idea if this answer (and mine) were identical - but I'd argue that the "highest rated" answer is actually the least complete atm...

Comment: @ReedCopsey You just try to justify your action. What is so hard in accepting that spender was the first to give the correct answer(ignoring a lot of bla blas)

Comment: @I4V Nothing, and I'm one of the people who upvoted him ;)  But I don't think it's the *best* answer, and I generally try to accept the best answer, not the first.